# Adding numbers to an image based on co-ordinates

Tags: images

I'm very new to WordPress and trying to work out an issue that in theory is easy but in practice has been frustratingly difficult.

I have a database with 5 columns and each contains a co-ordinate. I want to create a page where a user selects some filters and it returns the corresponding row of 5 co-ordinates. I then want these co-ordinates to be added onto a picture of a map as numbers that reflect the column number.

I.e. user filters imply row 5, where column 1 is co-ordinates (a,b) and column 2 is co-ordinates (c,d).. so on the picture a number (1) will appear at (a,b) and a (2) at (c,d).. preferably I'd also add an arrow pointing from 1 to 2 (and 2 to 3, etc..) but starting simple!

Edit: The picture is a map that I have and doesn't need to be uploaded by the user!

How would you suggest I approach this problem?

Thanks!

p.s. I can code this functionality on Python, if that helps!

Comment: Since you're using a custom table, I'm not sure how WP fits into this other than that the end result needs to be embedded? Image modification isn't a WP problem but a general PHP problem, the code to generate the image with the arrows, and figure out how to show the coordinates is going to be the same wether it's a standalone PHP program, or embedded inside WP

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks for replying. I was hoping there would be a WP specific solution as I do not know PHP and do not want to have to learn it. I suppose I could try through Python>PHP?

Comment: You'd need to know PHP to understand any WP based solution anyway. It would be easier to learn basic PHP, or setup a python app, than it would be to merge the two. Fundamentally PHP isn't that different though, a standard C based syntax like JS/C/C++/C#/etc that shares a lot of the same fundamental library functions with slightly different parameter ordering. WP does provide an image API, but it's more for basic resizing, it's not a general purpose drawing API. GD, ImageMagick extensions are available for PHP so those will do what you're hoping for